# Zend Route Multi Array Parameter Foward

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, routes

Adding routes to perform a friendly url in my application, i found a obstacle...:

This is tha actual url:

http://website.local/search?filter[type]=1&filter[sub_type]=6&filter[city]=Sao Paulo

I need change to

http://website.local/property/house/big/Sao Paulo

Type and sub Type is ok,i make a parameter and dinamyc create a route for then, but
city filter is a problem.

if i use:

```
Zend_Controller_Router_Route("'property/'.strtolower($type["name"]).'/' . strtolower($sub_type["name"])."/:city",'frontend','search','index',$params);",$params);
```

:city is forwarded, but like this:

```
array
  'city' => string 'sao paulo' (length=9)
  'module' => string 'frontend' (length=8)
  'controller' => string 'search' (length=6)
  'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
  'filter' => 
    array
      'type' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sub_type' => string '6' (length=1)
```

And i need to be this:

```
array
  'module' => string 'frontend' (length=8)
  'controller' => string 'search' (length=6)
  'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
  'filter' => 
    array
      'type' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sub_type' => string '6' (length=1)
      'city' => string 'sao paulo' (length=9)
```

Have any way route this!!

Help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
$params = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();
    unset($params['module'], $params['controller'], $params['action'], $params['page']);
    //collect multiple params
    $multiple = array();
    foreach($params as $key=>$value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
          $multiple[$key]=$value;
          unset($params[$key]);
      }
    }

    if (!empty($multiple)) {
        $multiple = "?".http_build_query($multiple);
    } else {
        $multiple="";
    }
```

This is the URL code that is generated:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page'=>$this->previous)), 'default') . $multiple; ?>">
```